# safe array of VT_BSTR in C#

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

How do I create a safe array of VT_BSTR? I'm working with a COM library in C# that has a function with the following signature:

```
void Add(string Name, object Value);
```

The library documentation says that one of the ways to use the function is to pass "A safe array of VT_BSTR (string)" as Value. The example C++ code includes this line:

```
psa = SafeArrayCreate( VT_BSTR, 1, &bounds);
```

Any suggestions?

---

I finally found code that does work. Any idea why this works but just passing any array of strings doesn't?

```
var temp = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), 1);
temp.SetValue(value, 0);
ContextItems.Add("IManExt.SaveAsOptionCmd.SaveAsTypesArray", temp);
```

Comment: You're using COM DLL in C#?

Comment: Pass an object[] that contains strings.

Comment: @HansPassant That doesn't work. See my edit, please.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using COM in C#, so you don't need create the SafeArray. In your C# project, add a reference, you can find the the dialog has a COM tab, click that tab and find your COM dll, and add it as a reference, then it will create a C# wrapper assembly for the COM DLL, and you just use the functions and classes in this C# wrapper.

You don't need to deal with SafeArray, when use COM in C++, you have to use it.

Please read this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for details, it is old, but I think it still works.

Comment: That's what I did, and it doesn't work. That's why I posted this question. However, I did stumble across some code that does work. Please see the edit to my original question.